# how to restart an oscillator instantaneously in swift 3 using audiokit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am trying to make a button that plays an oscillator that has ADSR and if the button is pressed while the oscillator is already playing, I want it to override the already playing oscillator and replay the oscillator from the start.

This code achieves my goal, but the "sleep" is way too long; it needs to be instantaneous.

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
    envelope.stop()
    oscillator.stop()
    sleep(1)
    envelope.start()
    oscillator.start()
}
```

Comment: FYI - **Never** use `sleep` on the main thread.

Comment: I know sleep is not a good solution, it just shows what my goal is.

Comment: Why do you need to start and stop the oscillator?  If you're putting an amplitude envelope on it, you're not hearing the first cycles anyway.

Comment: I need to stop and start it because when I try to play the oscillator again, since it has already been started, the code must be stopped before it will replay the oscillator.